# Convert array of NSNumber to Swift enum

Tags: arrays, swift, enums

I'd like to populate this function from an Objective-C array of NSNumber of the same enum values but in Swift. I was wondering if there is a Swifty way to do this:

```
/// Objective-c
typedef NS_ENUM(uint32_t, PTYAction) {
  PTYActionBlockSpace
  PTYActionLeaveSpace
  PTYActionMuteSpace
  PTYActionUnmuteSpace
};

/// Swift
enum Action {
  case blockSpace
  case leaveSpace
  case muteSpace
  case unmuteSpace
}

func createAction(_ action:PTYAction) {
 switch action {
  case .blockSpace:
    return .blockSpace
  case .leaveSpace
    return .leaveSpace
  case .muteSpace
    return .muteSpace
  case .unmuteSpace
    return .unmuteSpace
  }
}

func createActions(_ actions: [NSNumber]) -> [Action] {
  // Populate this function.
}
```

Comment: The enum would have to have a RawRepresentable that matches just add the right type after the colon then you can use the rawValue

Comment: So 0 means `blockSpace` and 1 means `leaveSpace` etc?

Comment: @Sweeper yes, this should be correct

Answer (score 1):

Your enum should have concrete type representing the NSNumber value, i.e Integer.

```swift
enum Action: UInt32 {
  case blockSpace  // 0
  case leaveSpace  // 1
  case muteSpace   // 2
  case unmuteSpace // 3

  var objcEnum: DYNAction {
    switch self {
      case .blockSpace:
        return .blockSpace
      case .leaveSpace:
        return .leaveSpace
      case .muteSpace:
        return .muteSpace
      case .unmuteSpace:
        return .unmuteSpace
    }
  }
}

func createActions(_ actions: [NSNumber]) -> [Action] {
    actions.compactMap { Action(rawValue: $0.uint32Value) 
}

func createAction(_ actions: [DYNAction]) -> [Action] {
    actions.compactMap { Action(rawValue: $0.rawValue) }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited the question to include the objective-c. I think this answer would work but it could be fragile in the case that an enum value is added in objective c, it could cause a bug. I should have had the objective c in there from the beginning. I think I can figure out how to use the raw value somehow... I'll let you edit it, if not I'll add an answer...

Comment: @Rik I can see your obj-c enum type is uint32, so why would you convert it directly from obj-c enum to swift enum with that rawValue?

Comment: Swift enum can contain a property that helps convert back to objc-c enum if needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
 func createActions(_ actions: [NSNumber]) -> [Action] {
    var returnVal = [Action]()
    for item in actions {
      let action = PTYAction(rawValue: item.uint32Value)
      switch action {
      case .blockSpace:
        returnVal.append(action.blockSpace)
      case .leaveSpace:
        returnVal.append(action.leaveSpace)
      case .muteSpace:
        returnVal.append(action.muteSpace)
      case .unmuteSpace:
        returnVal.append(action.unmuteSpace)
      case .none:
        continue
      }
    }
    return retVal
  }
```